# Can't create a connection in Toad MySql

Tags: mysql, connection, toad

I can't create a simple connection to Toad MySQL.

In the creation process:

`Connection Type : TCP`

`User : My user name.`

I don't know which username i should put here? when i installed it the user name that appears or the username i put in order to download the installation?
`Password : Should i choose a password.` When i downloaded the installation and in the installation process i didn't have to choose a password.

```
DataBase: Does any meaning for lower cases or higher cases? 
Port : 3306
The error i got : "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To start connection for your Mysql Server is easy.

First when you try to do new connections you will need to choose TCP.

Then you need to fill up with these details :

```
Host: The ip address of the Mysql server

User: the username for mysql database

Password: the password for mysql database

Database: the name of the database

Port : leave this as default (3306)
```

After that you can make your connection.

Answer (score 0):

Change the default setting in my.cnf configuration file.

You may find that file in following location:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf

Change bind-address=127.0.0.1  to bind-address=your_server_ip

Restart the mysql server and then try to connect

[See Here](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-mysql/f/22/t/8559.aspx)